# How to change bootstrap selection color

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Hello I am quite new to using bootstrap and I decided to use their navbar with pill buttons on a practice website and upon selecting each button the highlighted color was blue by default and not the color I wanted(black) therefore I was wondering how I could change this. I have tried using their bg-dark, btn btn-dark classes and none seem to work so I went and tried to change the color in css but couldn't get the color to not apply when button was unselected, then I tried using ::active and could not get the button to stay black once selected. Below i'll add pictures and the code, any help is appreciated !

```
      <div class="container-fluid" id="uk">
    <ul
      class="nav nav-pills mb-3 justify-content-center"
      id="pills-tab"
      role="tablist "
    >
      <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
        <button
          class="nav-link active"
          id="pills-home-tab"
          data-bs-toggle="pill"
          data-bs-target="#pills-home"
          type="button "
          role="tab "
          aria-controls="pills-home "
          aria-selected="true"
          ari
        >
          HOME
        </button>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
        <button
          class="nav-link"
          id="pills-profile-tab"
          data-bs-toggle="pill"
          data-bs-target="#pills-profile"
          type="button"
          role="tab"
          aria-controls="pills-profile"
          aria-selected="false"
        >
          MENU
        </button>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
        <button
          class="nav-link"
          id="pills-contact-tab"
          data-bs-toggle="pill"
          data-bs-target="#pills-contact"
          type="button"
          role="tab"
          aria-controls="pills-contact"
          aria-selected="false"
        >
          FAQ
        </button>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content" id="pills-tabContent">
      <div
        class="tab-pane fade show active"
        id="pills-home"
        role="tabpanel"
        aria-labelledby="pills-home-tab"
      >
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Pariatur
        labore explicabo hic maiores suscipit debitis nam facere error
        quisquam corrupti, praesentium rem amet tenetur, ducimus a
        blanditiis tempore? Nihil, quam?
      </div>
      <div
        class="tab-pane fade"
        id="pills-profile"
        role="tabpanel"
        aria-labelledby="pills-profile-tab"
      >
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Odio neque
        odit quia quaerat tempore voluptatum nihil provident labore, a ipsum
        asperiores dicta minus quos voluptas at earum vitae aut doloremque!
      </div>
      <div
        class="tab-pane fade"
        id="pills-contact"
        role="tabpanel"
        aria-labelledby="pills-contact-tab"
      >
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Rerum
        suscipit aliquid officia quaerat ratione sunt corrupti
        exercitationem dolores quasi illo eaque tempore nam, iure temporibus
        laudantium mollitia reprehenderit nihil nobis.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS code attempted

```
1st attempt -

#pills-home-tab {
background-color: black;
}

2nd attempt - 

#pills-home-tab:active {
background-color: black;
}
```

Here below is a link of images to show better what I want to do;

[image]

Comment: The buttons are blue because the `$primary-color` is blue.    If you want buttons of a different color you should override the value of `$primary-color` to your intended color. Or you can use other types of buttons (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/buttons/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember that you have to position your custom style cheat below bootstrap to modify any style you want

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="mystyle.css">
```

I recommend you to use a code snippet to confirm if that's the way you configured it

Comment: This also worked perfectly, I didn't know the position of links mattered until now, thank you !

Answer (score 0):

in the bootstrap by default the class ".active" is blue

You can use:

```
.nav-pills .nav-link.active {
    background-color: #000; 
}
```

If the above answer don't work try out

```
.nav-pills .nav-link.active {
    background-color: #000 !important; 
}
```

Comment: The second option worked perfectly thank you !